# C# System.Security.Cryptography - why specify key and IV twice?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

Most of the examples that show how to encrypt using the AES code in System.Security.Cryptography look like this:

```
using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
{
   aes.Key = Key;
   aes.IV = IV;
   ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
```

Is it necessary to specify the key and IV twice - once to the Aes object and once to the CreateEncryptor() function?  Or in this case, since I've already specified the key and IV, can I call the form of CreateEncryptor() that takes no arguments?

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to. You can use [the `CreateEncryptor()` overload](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/b31308b03e8bd5bf779fb80fda71f31eb959fe0b/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/symmetricalgorithm.cs#L227-L229) (without parameters), if you used the properties to specify the values:

```
public virtual ICryptoTransform CreateEncryptor() {
    return CreateEncryptor(Key, IV);
}
```

Here's what [the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09d0kyb3.aspx) says:

> Creates a symmetric encryptor object with the current Key property and initialization vector (IV).

Or you can omit setting the properties and use the overload with arguments if you don't use the `aes` object afterwards to create other encryptors/decryptors.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you use Aes and encryptor instance.
To create encryptor, You can just write the following code without using the 2 assignment statements:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

  ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.createencryptor?view=net-5.0